# Visual Studio 2022 - Object browser or Class view for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visualization, visual-studio-2022, code-structure

I'm new to TypeScript and starting development in React/TypeScript in Visual Studio 2022.

Is there any tool or extension that could be used to visually browse the structure of TypeScript project or used **libraries .d.ts** files that would help me to quicky see the classes and members available?

Built-in Object browser and/or Class view tools seems to show nothing.

**Thank you for any tip how to visualize TypeScript project structure**.

- first update: good news, it looks like **ReShaper** plugin can do that job
- Q: **are there any other alternatives to ReShaper?**

[image]

[image]